# iTerm (mac command-line) asks annoying questions before quit

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, iterm

Running OS X 10.6 snow leopard. I like to open iTerm for a quick editing of files. And then quit it so I do not have to see it in the dock. 
This is what has happened: I upgraded iTerm to the most recent version.
When I now turn it off this happens. A dialog box comes up.

> Quit iTerm2? All sessions will be closed.  *Cancel *ok.

(Surely this is from preventing me accidentally quitting an ongoing process). The preferences in iTerm plus searching with Google gives me nothing, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a preference for that. See focused checkbox:

[image]

It's connected to the "Warn me" directly above it, as in, if there are active sessions, it'll be displayed anyway if "Warn me" is checked, but "Confirm" isn't. Uncheck both to never get bothered.

Comment: Thanks a million mate!, I was getting real pissed my computer babysitting me.

Comment: Is this is general tab in System preferences? I don't have this checkbox. [Check it](http://i.imgur.com/rMDrHRM.png). How I can remove this checkbox?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav It's the iTerm 2 preferences.

Comment: Yeah my bad. It is my second day with macOS (I mean in life). I didn't remember that I have to open app preferences throught menu at top left of the screen (not window, like at Windows)